# Why is DCFL not closed under kleene star?

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata, kleene-star

I honestly haven't an idea how to proof that eventhough I can understand the background, could someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you tell us more about what attempts you've made?  What context-free languages do you know that aren't DCFL?  Where have you looked?  Have you checked in standard textbooks?

Comment: L1 = {a
n
b
mc
m ∣ n, m ≥ 0}That's what I thought to do: L ∪ {0} ∈ DCFL und (L ∪ {0})∗∉ DCFL.